xmlBeans-5.2.1.jar @Override error due to a class named Override
I am trying to compile xsd into corresponding Java files through xmlbeans-5.2.1 using below taskDef
<taskdef name="xmlbean"
    classname="org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean"
    classpath="path/to/xmlbeans.jar" />

However because there is an Override class defined in few of the xsd schemas, I am keep getting below error during compilation
error: incompatible types: Override cannot be converted to Annotation
  [xmlbean]             @Override

I cannot make changes to xsd schemas as it is given from someone
It is mistaking that source of annotation is from the class generated by the schema instead of java.lang.Override
Does anyone know a fix to above?
Successful compilation

The answer was to include NoAnnotation="true"
